# How to read a value from an inputHidden using JSF/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a problem with my input in a form. I would like to get a value stored in an inputHidden but it doesn't work.

JSF Code :

```
<h:form id="testForm">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="list" ...>
               ....
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:inputHidden id="codeShop" value="#{myBean.codeShop}" />
    <h:commandButton immediate="true" value="#{bundle.print}" 
                        onclick="return test();"/>
```

JS Code :

```
function test(){
    var codeShop = document.getElementById("testForm:codeShop").value;
    var list = document.getElementById("testForm:list").value;
    ...
}
```

I succeed to get the selectOneMenu value but document.getElementById("testForm:codeShop") doesn't work.

Generated HTML output :

```
<input id="testForm:codeShop" type="hidden" name="testForm:codeShop"/>
```

I don't understand why my value is not in my inputHidden. Is this normal?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you implying that `#{myBean.codeShop}` is not `null` at the moment the HTML output is produced by JSF? In other words, when you replace `<h:inputHidden>` by `<h:inputText>`, a non-empty input field is rendered?

Comment: Effectively, the input field is empty. It's odd because codeShop is set. I think the problem comes from an error in my xhtml. I will add more information in my first post.

Comment: Oh, i have found where was my mistake! When i click on a link, i call an action into my bean, then i update the render with the attribute render. <rich:panelMenuItem action="#{myBean.doUpdate}" label="#{bundle.link_first}"         render="formulaire">
...       </rich:panelMenuItem>

My inputHidden was out of the updated html (id="formulaire"). I have moved my <inputHidden .../> into it and now it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the code, as this is the correct code for getting value by Id.

`function test(){
    var codeShop = document.getElementById("codeShop").value;
    var list = document.getElementById("list").value;
    ...
}`